# Remove default fields from Product Collection

Tags: product, collection, product-collection

I have a product collection object (Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection).  I am adding various attributes to the select via `addAttributeToSelect()`.

How do I **remove** the default attributes e.g `entity_id, created_at` etc, from the collection?

I have tried `removeAttributeToSelect()`, but i believe this only removes attributes that have been added by `addAttributetoSelect().`

Comment: Have you use `addAttributeToSelect(*)`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I am the original poster. I thought it would use my other stackexchange account.

I have solved  this by using unsetData($key) on the product object, rather than the collection.  Unfortunately, this means looping through all the products, so it is rather slow.

And removeAttributeToSelect() does exist....http://doc4dev.net/doc/Magento/1/source-class-Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract.html#822-836

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. i have check that function is exits...

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone, there is a method **removeAllFieldsFromSelect**. It works well for me. Then you can add only the attributes you need with **addFieldToSelect**.

```
$orderCollection->removeAllFieldsFromSelect()
    ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
;
```

**Important notice:** field *entity_id* will be present anyway, removeAllFieldsFromSelect doesn't remove it.